# How I can find native_request_wait cpp code in android sdk?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am working android usb project.
I have some problem in usb read/write.
So, I need debug my project.
I am using `requestWait` function for `read`.
So, I can find `requestWait` function from
`Android_Sdk\sources\android-28\android\hardware\usb\UsbDeviceConnection.java`

And, there is `native_request_wait` function, but I cannot find the `native_request_wait` function's body.

**Question:** I mean I need the cpp code of `native_request_wait`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.java and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_hardware_UsbDeviceConnection.cpp. Specifically, [line 223](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_hardware_UsbDeviceConnection.cpp#223).

Comment: So, I can see the function code, but I cannot change this function or debug?

Comment: You cannot change this function, just like you cannot change the Java method that calls it. You can launch debugger, but the native (C++) debugger in Android Studio may not be very easy to apply to this function.

Comment: Ok, I cannot debug the native_cpp function of SDK.